# Ruby In-Place Edit Inside Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, string, text, scripting

I'm writing a script where one of the pieces of work I need to perform is to replace every instance of a string in a file with an empty string, before going on to do some other work. I'd prefer to edit in place instead of reading in the whole file, doing a gsub, and writing it back out.

I know I can do this on the command line:

```
ruby -pi.bak -e "gsub(/MyText/, '')" INSERT_FILE_NAME
```

But since I need to perform some other scripting operations after this, how can I perform this operation from inside a Ruby script?

Comment: not sure it's the best way, but you can just call it with backticks and interpolation

Comment: @maxpleaner nice! super new to Ruby and didn't know this was possible. Feel free to write up an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0):

There is no "real" in-place edit, even in the example you gave; it just looks like one. In fact, Ruby reads one file, writes the modified one, and renames them. That's why you get a bak file.

If the file fits into your memory, you could read the whole file into a Ruby variable, perform the replacement on the string, and then write the string out to a file of the same name. Technically speaking, it is not really "in place editing" either, but comes very close to what you are looking for.